# Linq to Entitites query cannot convert Int to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am making a search index. I got it working pretty good but I cannot incorporate ItemID (item numbers) in my search because i am having trouble converting the String in the TextBox.Text to a int in order for it to be a comparable type.

```
var q = (from t0 in db.Item
         join t1 in db.Categories on t0.CategoryID equals t1.CategoryID
         join t2 in db.Divisions on t0.DivisionID equals t2.DivisionID
         where t0.DivisionID == DDLInt &&
         //Contains
         (t0.ItemName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
         t0.Email.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
         t0.Description.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
         t0.Phone.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
         t0.ItemID.Equals(txtSearch.Text.Trim())) 
               // ^ This is the line where  
               //   it breaks because it is not a comparable type
         group t0 by new
         {
```

I am not sure how to convert or parse it and still have the search work properly.

Comment: I made a mistake sorry i am new.  It is saying i am using Linq to Entities and not Linq to SQL with i am confused with that. But it is not letting me using the Parse or convert.

Comment: ` LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` is the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either parse the `string` to an `int`:

```
t0.ItemID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text.Trim())))
```

or convert the `int` to a `string`:

```
t0.ItemID.ToString().Equals(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
```

or take the conversion out of the query:

```
int searchID;
if !int.TryParse(txtSearch.Text.Trim(),out searchID)
    searchID = -1;  // set to an invalid ID

var q = (from t0 in db.Item
     <snip>
     t0.ItemID.Equals(searchID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Should simply be:

```
t0.ItemID.Equals(int.Parse(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t0.ItemID.Equals(Int32.Parse(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that it will be a valid integer you can use `int.Parse`.  If you are unsure if it's a valid integer you can use `int.TryParse` and possibly prompt the user to re-enter if it's not valid.

It is generally best to validate all items before building the query (check that numbers are numbers, dates are dates, choice values are a valid choice, etc.).  If something is invalid you can save yourself a database query by checking it at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**int.Parse**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

```
t0.ItemName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
```

**would be**

```
int.Parse(t0.ItemName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
```